# Visual basic code working in one instance but not another

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have code that merges duplicates from one column, and concatenates their corresponding adjacent data into a cell. I have tested it, and it works, but when I run it on real world data it is deleting the concatenated data. I have made sure both columns were in text form,rather than formula form . I tested both real world columns independently with dummy data and it worked.  Any explanation or tips as to why it is working in my tests but not the real data? The data on the left of this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sejLx.png) is the real world data. The data on the right is an example of a successful test. I also ran successful tests concatenating empty cells, and letters.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
'Update 20131202
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Dic As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address,      Type:=8)
Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
arr = WorkRng.Value
For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
xvalue = arr(i, 1)
If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = Dic(arr(i, 1)) & " " & arr(i, 2)
Else
    Dic(arr(i, 1)) = arr(i, 2)
End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
WorkRng.ClearContents
WorkRng.Range("A1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) =     Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.keys)
WorkRng.Range("B1").Resize(Dic.Count, 1) =     Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Dic.items)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        End Sub
```

Comment: "deleting the concatenated data" means what exactly?

Comment: When I apply my VBA code to the real world collumns, it will sort the first column as expected but the entire second column will be blank.

Comment: How large is your real-world data?  Have you tested a smaller sub-set?  Your code works for me with test data, and without any actual real data to test it's difficult to suggest what the problem might be.  Can you share your data file?

Comment: Hello Tim, thankyou for the assistance. the code only works for comparing two columns. I left the first three columns un-merged, as to give you the data in its raw form, but I merged them into one when I attempted this for myself.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DEGa0WxJ1-S2NEWTVYUXNNbHM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey tim, one final stipulation: I need to concatenate the common values into the cell next to the corresponding column entry. Are you able to assist?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible the dictionary items are too large for transpose to handle: try this instead -

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim WorkRng As Range, xTitleId, i, xvalue
    Dim Dic As Variant
    Dim arr As Variant

    xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, _
                                  WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    arr = WorkRng.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        xvalue = arr(i, 1)
        If Dic.Exists(xvalue) Then
            Dic(xvalue) = Dic(xvalue) & " " & arr(i, 2)
        Else
            Dic(xvalue) = arr(i, 2)
        End If
    Next

    DictToRange Dic, WorkRng.Range("A1").Offset(0, 5)

End Sub

Sub DictToRange(d, rng As Range)
    Dim arr(), x As Long, k
    ReDim arr(1 To d.Count, 1 To 2)
    x = 1
    For Each k In d
        arr(x, 1) = k
        arr(x, 2) = d(k)
        x = x + 1
    Next k
    rng.Cells(1).Resize(d.Count, 2).Value = arr
End Sub
```